# Getting my drawing into pygame without .blit()

Tags: python, pygame

I've got my own drawing loaded on to the screen and scaled it to the size I want, but the background of the program I used to make the drawing is still on the image. I noticed that when I move the image, the background doesn't move with the picture, but it actually looks like it's stretching out and it will cover wherever I move the picture to. I think this is because I used the .blit feature when getting my picture on screen, but I can't find a clear enough answer on how to get the picture on screen any other way. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: *but the background of the program I used to make the drawing is still on the image* this sounds like you want to use an image with transparency (a.k.a. alpha channel), probably an png instead of a jpeg/bmp. *the background doesn't move with the picture, but it actually looks like it's stretching out and it will cover wherever I move the picture to* this sounds like you don't redraw your background before blitting your image to the screen.

Comment: Thank you, redrawing the background solved the issue. When I made the drawing I used FreshPaint, an ASUS app on my transformer book, and when I went to save it under pictures, it told me doing this would cause me to lose the transparency of the picture. I don't know how to fix that because I do have it saved as a png file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but the stretching might be caused by not redrawing the background. Blitting is like painting, you can't erase stuff. When you want to move something, you need to repaint all the places that have changed - also the background that is not visible after movement.

The quickest way to do this is to redraw the whole background.

Answer (score 0):

[**`screen.blit`**](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is used to draw an image on to the screen. An alternative way is to get each color of each pixel using an image program, and then drawing each pixel using [**`pygame.draw.rect`**](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect), but if you want to draw an image, `screen.blit` is the only option.